# How to use methods from one controller in another

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have installed waavi package for manipulation of translation files. I need to use methods from it's controller to mine? I tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
LanguageRepository::findByLocale(1);
```

This is what I am using in beginning of my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Waavi\Translation\Repositories\LanguageRepository;

use Waavi\Translation\Repositories\TranslationRepository;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
```

Comment: Are you using the correct namespaces? That method is not static by the way

Comment: I added code what I'm using in the beginning of my controller

Comment: Extend the controller that you want to use and call the method there.

Comment: but it's already extending Model is it possible to extend it once more

Comment: How php doesn't support more than once, it that something laravel?

Comment: Are you sure a file called `LanguageRepository` is a controller file?

Comment: jup... it's a controller(repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have successfully done all the steps in [here](https://github.com/Waavi/translation), you should be able to access to LanguageRepository using depedency injection(" It is recommended that you instantiate this class through Dependency Injection")

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Waavi\Translation\Repositories\LanguageRepository;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    private $language_repository;

    function __construct(LanguageRepository $language_repository)
    {
        $this->language_repository = $language_repository;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        dd($this->language_repository->findByLocale("en"));
    }
}
```

Note: you need pass language string instead of id to findByLocale method. see [line 97](https://github.com/Waavi/translation/blob/master/src/Repositories/LanguageRepository.php)